# jQuery - IE fadeIn(), then immediately fadeOut() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm not sure if this is a clicking issue, or specific to the jQuery fade functions.

I have the HTML structure like this: `label > input(hidden) + div + label text`

Example:

```
<label data-name="primary-residence" data-value="Yes">
    <input type="hidden" id="primary-residence" name="Primary Residence" value="" />
    <div class="big-check-box"></div>
    Primary Residence
</label>
```

And the jQuery is as follows:

```
$('label').on('click', function(){
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    if($(this).find('.big-check-box').hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).find('.big-check-box').removeClass('checked');
        $('#'+name).val('');
        $('#'+name+'-value, #'+name+'-loan-balance').fadeOut();
    }else{
        $('#'+name).val(value);
        $(this).find('.big-check-box').addClass('checked');
        $('#'+name+'-value, #'+name+'-loan-balance').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

I have a `big-box` that acts as a checkbox and has data attributes that then populate a hidden field to be collected on form submission. It also applies a class to the checkbox and fades in two new input fields.

Everything works fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE, the class doesn't get applied to the box and the new input fields fade in, then immediately fade out once the fade in animation is complete. Unless they are clicked twice, then it seems to work, but that isn't very intuitive or user friendly.

Here's a fiddle to a working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/vm5rkk1q/1/)

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

For some reason I needed to add `preventDefault()` for the IE fix. Not exactly why it works, but here's reference: [`<label>` - HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Here's the updated lines:

```
$('label').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    .....
});
```

Hope this can help someone else in the future.